# Как нормально использовать предикаты и функции из cctype в стандартных алгоритмах?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++17, clang, std

Решаю олимпиадную задачку в которой надо проанализировать регистр символов а потом их поменять. Написал следующее решение:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
...
std::string solve( std::string& str ) {
   size_t up_num = std::count_if( str.begin(), str.end(), std::isupper );
   size_t low_num = std::count_if( str.begin(), str.end(), std::islower );
   if ( up_num > low_num )
      std::for_each( str.begin(), str.end(), std::toupper );
   else
      std::for_each( str.begin(), str.end(), std::tolower );
   return str;
}
```

С компилятором Microsoft всё работает отлично, но LLVM и GCC отказываются это собирать. `std::count_if` не может принять `std::isupper` и `std::islower` в качестве предиката, а `std::for_each` не принимает `std::toupper` и `std::tolower` в качестве функтора. Если я правильно понял, это не из-за совпадения типов в сигнатуре функций cctype с тем, который выводят алгоритмы из итераторов. Как тут надо делать по нормальному, без использования промежуточных лямбд? Ведь навярняка, люди, которые это дизайнили, продумалил этот момент.

Comment: Прочитайте комментарий в https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper. `isupper` не совместим с алгоритмами. Тоже для `toupper`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper.

Comment: `toupper` не будет редактировать строку, как вы того хотите. Надо писать мутирующую лямбду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема происходит так как у `std::isupper` и `std::islower` несколько перегрузок, одни объявлены в `<cctype>`, другие в `<locale>`. Видимо по-умолчанию в vc++ и стандартной библиотеке gcc эти заголовочные файлы по-разному включены в другие заголовочные файлы. Если в vc++ явно заинклюдить `<locale>`, то перестает собираться и там.

В таких случаях следует явно приводить предикат к указателю на нужную перегрузку:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

void solve(::std::string & str)
{
    using t_Predicate = int ( * )(int);
    constexpr auto const p_up{static_cast<t_Predicate>(::std::isupper)};
    constexpr auto const p_low{static_cast<t_Predicate>(::std::islower)};
    auto const up_num{::std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), p_up)};
    auto const low_num{::std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), p_low)};
    if (low_num < up_num)
    {
        ::std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), p_up);
    }
    else
    {
        ::std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), p_low);
    }
    return;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:52,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:52,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:52,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:52,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccctype%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Avoid+solve(::std::string+%26+str)%0A%7B%0A%09using+t_Predicate+%3D+int+(+*+)+(int)%3B%0A%09constexpr+auto+const+p_up%7Bstatic_cast%3Ct_Predicate%3E(::std::isupper)%7D%3B%0A%09constexpr+auto+const+p_low%7Bstatic_cast%3Ct_Predicate%3E(::std::islower)%7D%3B%0A%09auto+const+up_num%7B::std::count_if(str.begin(),+str.end(),+p_up)%7D%3B%0A%09auto+const+low_num%7B::std::count_if(str.begin(),+str.end(),+p_low)%7D%3B%0A%09if+(low_num+%3C+up_num)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09::std::for_each(str.begin(),+str.end(),+p_up)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09else%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09::std::for_each(str.begin(),+str.end(),+p_low)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09return%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.412532637075714,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:25.59456398640997,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:74.40543601359003,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:45.587467362924286,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

З.Ы. Предикаты из cctype вообще лучше не использовать, так как они могут неявно задействовать текущую локаль. Делайте лучше сначала один обычный цикл, подсчитывая количество букв в верхнем / нижнем регистре, а потом второй обычный цикл для преобразования регистра.

Comment: Есть еще проблема - в эти предикаты нельзя передавать отрицательные символы, иначе будет UB. Поэтому параметр надо кастовать к `unsigned char`...

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает т.к. у [`std::isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) есть дополнительный [перегруженный вариант](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isupper), приинимающий локаль, объявленый в `<locale>`. Можно явно привести тип:

```
std::count_if( str.begin(), str.end(), static_cast<int (*)(int)>(std::isupper));
```

А можно использовать Сишный `::isupper()`:

```
std::count_if( str.begin(), str.end(), ::isupper);
```

С остальными функциями всё аналогично.

---

[`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) работает не так как ты рассчитываешь: он не меняет исходную строку; здесь нужен [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper );
```

А если выпендрёж с функциональщиной вызван не религиозным рвением, то можно просто использовать обычный цикл:

```
for(char &c: str) {
  c = std::toupper((unsigned char)c);
}
```

---

А также, как напоминает *@HolyBlackCat*, `isupper()` и все прочие в принципе не стоит использовать с алгоритмами т.к. если `char` будет представлен знаковым типом, то при передаче в эти функции напрямую они дадут UB для отрицательных значений.

Comment: Есть еще проблема - в эти предикаты нельзя передавать отрицательные символы, иначе будет UB. Поэтому параметр надо кастовать к `unsigned char`...

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за уточнение; добавил в ответ...

Comment: `А можно использовать Сишный ::isupper` Стандарт языка гарантирует, что Сишный `isupper` находится в глобальном пространстве имён?

Comment: @wololo, подписываться под этим я бы не стал, но ЕМНИП это выводится из других требований и я почти уверен, что на практике это всегда так...

Comment: `это выводится из других требований` пример?

Comment: @wololo, цитаты сейчас искать не буду, но ЕМНИП там требуется наличие библиотек Си и как-то должно быть описано, как они должны интегрироваться... хотя я могу и безбожно врать...